# Sending fax via smartphones\android

Tags: android, voip, fax

I am searching for a way to send fax via android phone.
Sending fax uses converting voice to data, its been done for years on land wire phones
by calling to remote fax playing the voice we all familier with and thats it.
So how\is it possible that the android phone will call to othe fax and convert some img file
to voice and will play this voice one it called to other fax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be an hard work.

I would use a web serivce (yes, need to be paid)...

http://www.interfax.net/it/dev/webservice

Try to look at this:

http://code.google.com/p/freeboxmobile/

good luck

Comment: its not free - its service that billed according to number of sent pages. how can it be that there is not way to convert documnet to voice fax on android

Comment: I'm with you, I hate to pay for something that should be resolved a long time ago... I posted my answer just to inform that there are "modern" ways to send/receive fax.

Comment: I would buy app that allow sending unlimited fax pages ,but never app that limit me to pages. its not reasonable...

Comment: another question like your: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090522/is-there-any-native-app-for-android-fax

Answer (score 0):

FAX is a bi-directional protocol that goes through several stages of handshake before the actual image data is sent. Even if you could write an Android app to listen and "speak" the correct audio tones, the QOS (quality of service) of cellular voice is lower than that of land lines and would not succeed. The only FAX capability offered by some mobile service providers allows you to receive a fax to your mobile number and it will get stored to voicemail. From there you can forward the message to a land line to print it out at a later time.

As others have mentioned, your best bet is to use a web (cloud) based API for sending and receiving faxes.